# Autocorrelation of a vector series

Tags: c#, performance

**Related:** [Autocorrelation of a vector series (2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/290953/199333)

The given C# source code computed [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) of a vector series.

The listing gives accurate results, but is horribly slow.

How can I optimize it to make it fast?

```
public class TimeSeriesAnalysisForVectors
{
    private static double C(int t, List<Vec3> vectors)
    {
        int n = vectors.Count;
        if (t >= n || t < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value for t. It must be between 0 and n-1.");

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - t; i++)
        {
            sum += vectors[i].Dot(vectors[i + t]);
        }

        return sum / (n - t);
    }

    public static (List<double> taus, List<double> autocorrs) 
        GetAutoCorrelationPoints(List<Vec3> vectors, int maxLag)
    {
        var tValues = new List<double>();
        var cResults = new List<double>();

        double c0 = C(0, vectors); // This is the normalization factor
        Console.WriteLine($"Normalization factor: {c0}");

        for (int lag = 0; lag <= maxLag; lag++)  // Start from 0 to include the autocorrelation at lag 0
        {
            try
            {
                double cValue = C(lag, vectors);

                Console.WriteLine($"Lag={lag}, Raw Autocorr={cValue}, Normalized Autocorr={cValue / c0}");
                tValues.Add(lag);
                cResults.Add(cValue / c0); // Normalization is done here
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
        return (tValues, cResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `C` is not the greatest name. It does not tell what the function does, and it is too short, easy to miss. It took me a while to find where it is used.

  The first argument is better to be `lag`, not `t`.

  `c0` is better to be `normFactor`. Then you may safely drop the comment.
- Throwing `ArgumentException` doesn't feel right. `C` is a private method, and you are in full control of how it is called. This exception may never happen, and checking a validity of `t` is a waste of cycles.
- `cValue` is never used. It is OK to drop it.
- Regarding performance. It is not possible to optimize *this* code. It has a quadratic time complexity, and will be slow no matter how you modify it. You need a better algorithm. Specifically, using [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Efficient_computation) would reduce time complexity to \$O(n\log n)\$

Comment: Can FFT be applied to a vector?

Comment: @user366312 Why not? Fourier transform doesn't care of the nature of the values, as long as you can add them and multiply by a scalar.