# Autocorrelation of a vector series (2)

Tags: c#, vectors

**Related:** [Autocorrelation of a vector series](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/290931/199333)

The given C# source code computes the autocorrelation of a vector series using a Fast Fourier Transform.

Can you review this code for correctness?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;

public class TimeSeriesAnalysisForVectors
{
    private static Complex[] FFT(Complex[] x)
    {
        int n = x.Length;
        if (n == 1)
            return new Complex[] { x[0] };

        Complex[] even = new Complex[n / 2];
        Complex[] odd = new Complex[n / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            even[i] = x[2 * i];
            odd[i] = x[2 * i + 1];
        }

        Complex[] evenTransformed = FFT(even);
        Complex[] oddTransformed = FFT(odd);

        Complex[] result = new Complex[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            double angle = -2 * Math.PI * i / n;
            Complex twiddle = Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(1, angle);
            result[i] = evenTransformed[i] + twiddle * oddTransformed[i];
            result[i + n / 2] = evenTransformed[i] - twiddle * oddTransformed[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static Complex[] FourierTransform(List<Vec3> vectors)
    {
        int n = vectors.Count;
        Complex[] fftInput = new Complex[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fftInput[i] = new Complex(vectors[i].X, 0);
        }

        // Compute FFT
        return FFT(fftInput);
    }

    private static List<double> ComputeAutoCorrelation(Complex[] fftInput)
    {
        int n = fftInput.Length;
        List<double> autoCorrelations = new List<double>();

        // Compute auto-correlation using the FFT result
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            autoCorrelations.Add((fftInput[i] * Complex.Conjugate(fftInput[i])).Real / n);
        }

        return autoCorrelations;
    }

    public static List<double> GetAutoCorrelationPoints(List<Vec3> vectors, int maxLag)
    {
        var fftInput = FourierTransform(vectors);
        var autoCorrelations = ComputeAutoCorrelation(fftInput);

        // Extract autocorrelation values up to maxLag
        var result = new List<double>();
        for (int lag = 0; lag <= maxLag && lag < autoCorrelations.Count; lag++)
        {
            result.Add(autoCorrelations[lag]);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```